# How can I work out the ratio between the number of home runs this player had in baseball-reference.com

Tags: baseball

How can I work out the ratio between the number of home runs this player had and the number of balls he hit (as opposed to struck out) using this table?

http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/m/marisro01.shtml

[image: Roger Maris Career Stats]

i.e. I have the strike outs and the number of home runs but I am not sure how many he hit from the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column labeled 'H' is total hits, including home runs.  The "Glossary" link next to the chart near the top will explain what the heading of each column means.